# Removing Java Applet Warning Popup

Tags: java, applet

I have searched around but cannot find the definitive answer to my question.

We have a Java Applet we wish to deploy into an internal system. The applets job is to access an external device via a java Socket.

I have self signed the certificate of the applet locally for development purposes and the applet works correctly. With the self signed certificate, i get a popup warning asking me if i wish to run the applet.

Once the code goes live, it will be used on the same browser for just our internal users. If i get a trusted certificate from somewhere like verisign, etc, will the popup warning be disabled?

Ideally, i do not want the user to have to confirm anything or have to check any boxes, etc.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: *"it will be used on the same browser for just our internal users."*  Do you control the machines it will run on?  If so, you might be able to edit the policy file for those machines to always trust your applet.

Comment: Yes - we have full control of the machines it will run on and also the browser version that is running the application.  I`ll see if i can find some more information on how the policy file works and how it can help me.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A notification window will always popup the first time the applet is run this is unavoidable as user confirmation is required for the thing to run.

What you can do is ensure you have signed the applet with a valid certificate from a registered CA and modify your applet's manifest file with the correct security attributes listed here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/secman.html).

If you are using Maven to build your JAR here is the appropriate plugin entry to alter your manifest:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            <manifestEntries>
                <!-- 
                Extra manifest attributes required to run the applet
                without security prompts.
                -->
                <Codebase>https://example.com</Codebase>
                <Permissions>all-permissions</Permissions>
                <Application-Name>Example Name</Application-Name>
                <Caller-Allowable-Codebase>*</Caller-Allowable-Codebase>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks - so is the signing of the applet with a valid certificate with the relevant attribute settings still not going to get rid of the notification window the first time it is run?

Comment: We already have an applet in our code base - like this - <applet height="0" width="0" code="../applet/APPLETNAME.class"></applet>.

Comment: This is does`nt cause a popup at all, even when developing, Unfortunately this was created and built a long time ago, so there is no documentation on it.

Comment: The new applet is defined like this in the JSP -

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
var attributes = {name:'APPLETNAME',
 codebase:'.',
    code:'com.APPLET',
    archive:'APPLETNAME.jar',
    width:1, height:1} ;
var parameters = {fontSize:16} ;
var version = '1.5' ;
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>